# If $\sum c_{n} (z-a)^n$ has a radius of convergence $R$ show $\sum c_{n} n(z-a)^{n-1}$ does as well

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, proof-verification

> If the series, $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n} (z-a)^{n}$$
>
> has a radius of convergence, $R$. Show,
>
> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n} n(z-a)^{n-1} $$
>
> has the same radius of convergence.

My proof:

The power series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n} (z-a)^{n}$$ having a radius of convergence $R$ means that, $$\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}|=R$$

Let $k_n=nc_n$, by definition $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} k_{n} (z-a)^{n-1} $$ is also a power series so the same theorem should apply.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{nc_{n}}{(n+1)c_{n+1}}|=R \lim_{n \to \infty} |1-\frac{1}{n}|=R$$

Q.E.D

Is my proof correct? Does anyone else have another proof method?

Comment: The proof is not correct, for radius of convergence $R$ does not imply that $|c_{n}/c_{n+1}|$ has limit $R$.  One can prove the result by the limsup argument of the answer, or by working directly with the meaning of radius of convergence.

Comment: @AndréNicolas We are assuming that the first series has a radius of convergence R. Meaning if the limit for $|c_{n}/c_{n+1}|$ exists then it is $R$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So what you are saying is that my proof does not cover cases in which the limit does not exist for instance $c_{n}=1+(-1)^n$?

Comment: That's exactly the point, the limit need not exist.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply Hadamard's formula of the radius of convergence.

Given the series 
$$
\sum^{+\infty}_{n=0}c_n(z-a)^n
$$
its radius of convergence $\rho_1$ is 
$$\frac{1}{\rho_1} = \limsup_{n \to \infty}  \sqrt[n]{\vert c_n  \vert}$$ 
Given the series 
$$
\sum^{+\infty}_{n=0}c_n n(z-a)^{n-1}
$$
then, its radius of convergence $\rho_2$ is
$$\frac{1}{\rho_2} = \limsup_{n \to \infty}  \sqrt[n-1]{n\vert c_n  \vert}$$
Now, since we know $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n-1]{n}=1$, we have 
$$\frac{1}{\rho_2} = \limsup_{n \to \infty}  \sqrt[n-1]{n\vert c_n  \vert}=(\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n-1]{n})\limsup_{n \to \infty}  \sqrt[n-1]{\vert c_n  \vert}=\limsup_{n \to \infty}  \sqrt[n]{\vert c_{n+1}  \vert}=\limsup_{n \to \infty}  \sqrt[n]{\vert c_n  \vert}=\frac{1}{\rho_1}$$
So we have $\rho_1=\rho_2$.